# Javascript/JQuery program only works after refresh in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, keyframe

This app is a virtual turntable, so when you click the `<div id="on-off-knob">`, the turntable should start spinning. This is the only part of the program I'm currently concerned about, clicking the on/off knob after the page loads so the table will spin. To be clear, `<div id="matt" class="rotate-matt">` should spin. But it doesn't work in Safari after initial load.

My Javascript program runs perfectly in FF and Chrome, but in Safari, it only runs correctly after refreshing the page after it has loaded once. There are no errors to speak of. I've looked at countless other "solutions" to problems that are similar, but none work and the solutions are inconsistent (issues with `@keyframe` animations, re-structuring how the page is loaded, different versions of JQuery and more).

From everything I've seen, it seems this is a caching issue, or something just isn't being loaded the first time. In my Safari dev tools console, it shows the number of "resources" being loaded. That number is always smaller on the first load and bigger when refreshed, or at least the number seems to change, which I wouldn't expect. So something isn't being loaded, or at least that's what I interpret that to mean. I don't know how to test for this.

Because there are so many possible variables, here is some html and javascript for context, but I will provide a codepen and a link to the actual running program on Github as well.

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="table-base">
    <!-- On/off knob -->
    <div id="on"></div>
    <div id="off"></div>
    <div id="knob-base"></div>
    <div id="on-off-knob">
        <div id="knob-select"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Platter that spins -->
    <div id="platter"></div>
    <div id="matt" class="rotate-matt">
        <div id="spindle"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Tone arm with needle -->
    <img src="img/tone_arm_new.png" id="tone-arm" class="tone-arm-off">
    <div id='vinyl-placeholder'></div>
</div>
```

Relevant JS:

```
//Check rotate vinyl or matt
if(recordLoaded == true){
    //Rotate vinyl
    $('#vinyl-rotate').css('animation-play-state', 'running');
}
else{
     //Rotate matt
     $('#matt').css('animation-play-state', 'running'); 
}
```

The JS is part of a larger click event and I'm only concerned with the `$('#matt').css('animation-play-state', 'running');` portion.

Here is a stripped down version of the entire program on codepen: [Space Vinyl Codepen](https://codepen.io/codemensch/pen/MqpLjb)

**The bug doesn't happen on codepen in Safari**, so not sure what that means. Here is the full program live on Github [Space Vinyl Github](https://codemensch.github.io/space_vinyl/), clicking the knob should produce no action on first load. Also, here is the full repository [Space Vinyl Repository](https://github.com/codemensch/space_vinyl)

Comment: I think Your code is being executed before jQuery load or something. Have You wrapped Your code with: `$(function () { your code here });` ?

Comment: Just tried this, but didn't seem to work, I wrapped my entire program in it, though not sure if that is correct. What does this accomplish?

Comment: I've enabled developer panel in Safari and activated ignoring cache. And it was non-working always. So it seems like something not loading in time. Check Yourself

Comment: Hi @codemensch did you find a solution in the end?